# Android standalone menu button with React native

Tags: android, menu, react-native, android-menu

I need to make a standalone (without additional bars or else) menu button in my React Native (v 0.47.2) Android app:

[image: Menu closed]

On touch it has to open side menu:

[image: Menu opened]

Which component I need to use?

Comment: ```<View/>``` with absolute position and an Icon? Or are you using React Navigation?

Comment: I'm using React Navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `react-navigation`. Use the `StackNavigator`. The `StackNavigator` can set `Headers`. In the `Header`, there is a `prop` to which you can pass an `Icon` (or any `Component`).
Here an example:

```
// all your other imports
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import {
    Platform,
} from "react-native";

const MenuButton = ({ navigate }) => {
    return (
        <Icon
            name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-menu-outline" : "md-menu"}
            onPress={() => navigate("DrawerOpen")}
        />
    )
}

StackNavigator({
    Notifications: {
        screen: Example,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerLeft: <MenuButton {...navigation} />,
        }),
    },
```

The `headerLeft` (or `headerRight`) can be used for you case ([Documentation)](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack). Here I pass `<MenuButton />` component. You can set the color of the `StackNavigator`s `Header` to the `backgroundColor` of your app, or `transparent`. That way, there won`t be anything visible, but the menu button.

Of yourse you would need to stack you `StackNavigator` in a `DrawerNavigator` for the `onPress={() => navigate("DrawerOpen")}` to work.
In the `DrawerNavigator` you can use a `contentComponent` which you pass your custom component, that contains your menu.

Here is a more complex setup http://rationalappdev.com/cross-platform-navigation-in-react-native/

Comment: Thanks. I thought, there's a special component which contains both icon and menu (for further compatibility issues or something like this), just like titlebar in StackNavigator. But the way it's made is good too.